# Issue with CMake in GitHub actions

Tags: github, cmake, github-actions

https://github.com/blguru20/capicxx-core-runtime/commit/d6a25e2873deed1fe7bb924fa8edd6872f03f17a

My learn-github-actions.yml file:

```
name: learn-github-actions
on: [push]
jobs:
  check-bats-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name : "create and enter build dir"
        run: |
          mkdir build
          cd build
      - name : "run cmake "
        run: cmake ..
      - name : "run make " 
        run: make
```

"cmake .. " failing though the corresponding folder contains CMakeLists.txt file.

Here is the error as shown on GitHub actions

```
2s
Run cmake ..
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/runner/work/capicxx-core-runtime" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Link to the repository :

https://github.com/blguru20/capicxx-core-runtime

This works in local machine

What is the issue with yml file?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the checkout step of your repo. Also note the multiline command usage in the run section.

So your original script would look like this:

```
name: learn-github-actions
on: [push]
jobs:
  check-bats-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: "create and enter build dir"
        run: |
          mkdir build
          cd build
      - name: "run cmake "
        run: cmake ..
      - name: "run make " 
        run: make
```

Additional to that you don't need to fiddle with creating a build dir and changing to it, CMake will do that for you. And using CMake's `--build` command you are able to  abstract the build tool call. When creating workflows try to be explicit with the CMake generator.

Your GitHub action script would then look like this:

```
name: learn-github-actions
on: [push]
jobs:
  check-bats-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: "Create build directory and run CMake"
        run: cmake -S . -B build -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
      - name: "Build Project" 
        run: cmake --build build --target all --config Release -- -j4
```